# Go To Other Language Page

Tags: php, jquery

I store my English website pages in a folder called "en". Then I store the Arabic version of the website pages in a folder called "ar". Both folders are still in local environment (localhost).

In each English website page, there is a button to go to the Arabic version of the page.

Here is the button code in the English web page (using href="echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']"):

http://jsfiddle.net/qBzb5/

But instead of going to the Arabic version of the web page, the button redirects me to the page itself. The link becomes:

http://localhost/the_website/en/the_page.php

What I want:

http://localhost/the_website/ar/the_page.php

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to replace the en with ar

```
<?php

 $file_name = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; 
 $file_name = str_replace("/en/","/ar/",$filename);

 echo $file_name;

?>
```

Comment: Why didn't I think about it? So simple! Thanks Jason.

Answer (score 1):

with `<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>` you are just linking to the same page. You have two ways to go about with this.

First have a base path, in your case this would be `http://localhost/the_website/`, in a variable, and then just echo that plus the language, plus the page itself, e.g.

```
<?php
$base = 'http://localhost/the_website/';
echo '<a href="'.$base.'en/the_page.php">button</a>';
?>
```

Then the other method is to just use a quick replace on `<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>`:

```
<a href="<?php echo str_replace('/en/', '/ar/', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) ?>">button</a>';
```

I'd recommend you take the first option.

Comment: I chose the second option, like the Josh answer before this. Thanks a lot Hosh Sadiq.